# datagridview con combo box

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola estoy intentando hacer un datagridview donde en una de las columnas haya un combo box `TcType {Fuera de Servicio, Normal)` (**Tipo de Canton)**. El codigo para rellenar el datagrid view es el siguiente:

```
    dataGridViewTcCnf.DataSource = ConfData2.TcCnf.TcCnfArray.ToList();
```

Donde mi arreglo TcCnfArray es un arreglo de objetos sTcCnf de 16 posiciones donde los atributos de sTcCnf son:
IdTc, TcType(es el que he vinculado con el combobox), NumUv, NumUvNormalizacion, IdUvNormalizacion y TcFlags.

Cuando en mi array en la posicion de TcType haya un 0 quiero que en el comboBox ponga Fuera de Servicio y cuando hay un 1 que ponga Normal. Como lo asigno?
Tengo creada la columna en el datagridview con el combobox y la colección es la que he dicho.

Para hacer la conversion en viceversa hago lo siguiente:

```
ConfData.TcCnf.TcCnfArray[index].TcType = Convert.ToByte(dataGridViewTcCnf.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value);
```

Me pone que el valor no es valido para el datagridview. 
No se como asignarle a la columna combo box del data grid view que cuando le llegue un 0 significa que el combo box selected index sea el 0 y escriba Fuera de Servicio.

La columna del combobox **Tipo de Canton**  tiene las siguientes propiedades. Debo configurar uno de estos campos para que cuando le llegue un entero a esa posición del datagridview se escriba el item correspondiente con el entero verdad? Cual seria?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi datagridview es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como le asigno que cuando legue 0 escriba/seleccione Fuera de servicio y que cuando llegue 1 escriba/selecione normal? Que le debo poner en ValueMember o DisplayMember para que se haga esta asignacion?

Cuando en lugar de tener un combo box en la columna de **Tipo de Canton**  tengo un text box mi resultado de leer la información del array TcCnfArray es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este resultado seria correcto solo tengo rellenadas las tres primeras posiciones del array lo que pasa es que no quiero ver un 1 en dicha columna quiero ver "Normal". Tengo todos los DataPropertyName de las columnas asignados con los valores del objeto sTcCnf.

Comment: esto es winforms no? si es asi agrega esa etiqueta. Habria que ver como esta definido el combo. Pero el combo tiene dos propiedas, una lista que se muestra y una lista donde tiene las claves de lo que se muestra. deberias cargar los numeros como claves y solo el combo va a mostrar lo que necesitas.

Comment: Vale lo intento y mañana te confirmo si me sale gracias!!

Comment: @gbianchi he modificado mi pregunta con una imagen de mi combobox

Comment: Faltan datos para poder ayudarte. Haría falta saber la definición de `TcCnfArray`, así como del DataGridView para ver la definición de las columnas. Sería muy bueno que pudieras montar un [mcve] para que sea mas fácil ver la solución

Comment: Creo que ahora esta un poco mas claro no es asi? @Pikoh

Comment: Lo he hecho por diseño. La definicion de todas ellas o solo la del combo box?

Comment: Creo que está bien asi. A ver si alguien puede ayudarte antes que yo, si no esta tarde prometo echarle un ojo

Comment: Vale gracias! @Pikoh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probablemente el problema sea por la forma en la que llenas las opciones del `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. No lo especificas, pero supongo que estás usando la colección `Items`. Haciéndolo así no hay manera de hacer el enlace, ya que solo añades una descripción.

Te explico como lo haría yo. En primer lugar, vamos a poner la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` a false para que el `DataGridView` no intente generar algo raro, y creamos un `DataTable` con dos columnas, una para la descripción y la otra para el valor que enlazará con los datos de la columna:

```
this.dataGridViewTcCnf.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataTable dtValores = new DataTable();
dtValores.Columns.Add("descripcion");
dtValores.Columns.Add("indice", typeof(int));
```

Rellenamos el `DataTable` con los posibles valores:

```
dtValores.Rows.Add("Fuera de servicio", 0);
dtValores.Rows.Add("Normal", 1);
```

Ahora añadimos el `DataSource` a la columna para que los valores se carguen en los combos:

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns[1]).DataPropertyName = "TcType";
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns[1]).DisplayMember = "descripcion";
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns[1]).ValueMember = "indice";
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns[1]).DataSource = dtValores;
```

<sub>(aquí he usado el indice de la columna, puedes hacer lo mismo o usar el nombre)</sub>

Las propiedades son muy importantes. `DataPropertyName` debe ser el nombre de la columna/propiedad con la que vamos a enlazar, y las otras dos especifican las columnas de valor y a mostrar que hacen referencia al `DataTable` que hemos creado.

Una vez hecho esto, todo debe funcionar de forma automática. Ejemplo:

```
sTcCnf[] TcCnfArray = new sTcCnf[] { new sTcCnf(){ IdTc=1, TcType=0 },
                                     new sTcCnf(){ IdTc=2, TcType=1 },
                                     new sTcCnf(){ IdTc=3, TcType=0 }};

this.dataGridView3.DataSource = TcCnfArray;
```

Comment: De acuerdo gracias!! Voy a prbarlo @Pikoh

Comment: Me va perfecto @Pikoh, lo que no consigo entender es que aveces se me borra el codigo ya que lo he escrito en el archivo .designer.cs y cuando toco algo del diseño de datagridview se me borra. Debo ponerlo ahi verdad? Gracias

Comment: @Xim123 El archivo designer nunca se debe editar manualmente, ya que es autogenerado por el visual studio. Todo el código debe ir en el archivo .cs del formulario. Si te refieres al código que te pongo, puedes ponerlo o bien en el constructor del formulario, o bien en el `Load` del mismo.

Comment: Vale gracias @Pikoh